# How to stop reload while using inspect element

Tags: google-chrome, mobile, google-chrome-app, page-refresh, inspect-element

Im trying to inspect something but when I get back to it then it disappears.
I have made a video on this issue here:

[The Issue](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=MZkv7_cpEUU)

So this is the website, when I press click to check the amount the amount is reloaded. The internet is off. How can I stop it from reloading?

I have made this work before but I don't remember how.
I remember that I had to download something about DOOM but... I'm not to sure.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. You shouldn't share videos/links from another sources.. Try to explain your problem right here. With examples..

Comment: Ok, I'll explain. Lets say that I wanna inspect my question, no problem, the internet is off, I wanna go to inbox (no internet) and there I wana also to inspect something ok then I'm back here and when I click on inbox to check what I changed I see that's reloaded. How can I block it?

Answer (score 3):

I was able to do this by pausing the debugger.

Right click on the element of interest then click inspect. Navigate to the Sources tab. Click the pause button (or press F8 or Ctrl + ).

[image: Debugger running]

Page will no longer refresh.

[image: Debugger paused]

Use the button at the top left of the interface to 'Select and element of the page to inspect it' (or use Ctrl + Shift + C). Then select your element of interest.

When the page tries to refresh the debugger will cause execution to pause.

Answer (score 0):

So you can block auto refresh on browsers I have found this website which I believe is what you are looking for.

It mentions downloading this [Auto Refresh Blocker](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/auto-refresh-blocker/nmhmgghfmjjoejobimppckbalonobkck?hl=en) from the chrome store.

In this extension you can blacklist sites to stop it from refreshing.

[image: Quick overview of links that have been added]

[Block Auto Refresh](https://www.maketecheasier.com/disable-web-page-auto-refresh-for-various-browsers/)

Comment: I tried, also in chrome://flags is everything disabled about reloading, sorry but I forgot to say that I inspect on chrome mobile. I know it works but I don't remember how I did it

Comment: Oh I didn't realize it was on mobile let me have a think and get back to you.

Comment: What I mean is that for example I inspect a page and when I click on something what I want it appears no problem (without refreshing the page) and inspect it, back to site but heres the problem when I get back there is reloaded (I don't open a new page) maybe is a script

Comment: Ok, so i have done some searching and it seems that you just need to go to here, then refresh after enabling it and you should be all good.

chrome://flags/#automatic-tab-discarding

Comment: Hmm seems that this'd be the solution, the single problem is that I cant find it on flags..just offline auto reload mode, only auto reload visible tabs and the pull to refresh effect, all of these are disabled but can't find automatic tab discarding, maybe chrome changed it in other name?

Comment: Nope...can't find it, chrome://flags/#automatic-tab-discarding, same.

Comment: @SeanCallanan I have find another site which has said this

**However, there is an extremely useful app here, called Type Machine [link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/d...emachine&hl=en)

Quite simply it saves everything you type in to any app so you can copy/paste it over should you lose it.**

So it won't stop the refreshing but if you loose what you type when it does refresh you can just put it straight back.